# Lambda Dead Letter Queue with SNS permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I am trying to use the Dead Letter Queue of Lambda. I have configured it to to send messages to an SNS Queue. I put in the an incorrect handler to make the Lambda invocation error out. The error messages never arrives in the SNS Queue. I believe this is a permissions issue. Below is the my Access policy set for the SNS queue

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:AddPermission",
        "SNS:RemovePermission",
        "SNS:DeleteTopic",
        "SNS:Subscribe",
        "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "SNS:Publish",
        "SNS:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:1234567:lambda-dlq",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "1234567"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The lambda function has a Role attached to that has the `sns:Publish`, `action` to `allow` and `resource` to `*`

Am i missing anything? any other reason the message might not arrive DLQ ?

Comment: DLQ are only for async invokations of lambda. Do you invoke your lambda asynchronously?

Comment: I invoke the lambda function using the test feature and also from an CW alarm which as far as I know is a asynchronous call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to verify your scenario. I observed that using Test in console does not produces messages in DLQ.

What worked was using CLI (haven't tested with CW Events):

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name ffff --invocation-type Event --profile my-profile /dev/stdout
```

Also the other settings were :

**SNS policy** (same as yours; default)

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:AddPermission",
        "SNS:RemovePermission",
        "SNS:DeleteTopic",
        "SNS:Subscribe",
        "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "SNS:Publish",
        "SNS:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxx:my-dlq-topic",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "xxxxxxx"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**lambda execution role**

Only added `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSNSFullAccess` for simplicity to it.

**async lambda settings**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, thats was the issue. Calling it from the CLI worked
I still don't understand why the "Test" in console  wouldn't generate an DLQ email. As far as i am aware that is an asynchronous call but i guess that may not be the case ...

Comment: @alexis No problem. I'm not sure that Test in console async. It did not work for me either, which may suggests is synchronous.

Comment: I used the web debugger in chrome ... and using the Test console going by the network logs I thing its making a synchronous call. I couldnt see anything in the HTTP header to confirm this mostly by the timing of the call and respond